# A way not to wait for Heroku to compile/Git pre-receive hook to finish

Tags: git, shell, heroku, push, githooks

I often push Rails builds to Heroku via Git. For those unfamiliar, code is pushed to Heroku with `git push`, and a pre-receive hook compiles the whole thing before validating reception.

The thing is, waiting for compilation is always long (typically 2 minutes for me) and adds up when one ends up pushing and re-pushing many small changes. Two minutes can turn into fifteen, while I'm being deprived of my shell.

Is there a way not to have to wait after that compilation/hook to finish to gain back my shell but still get feedback eg. if it fails?

I know about the suspend (`^Z`) command, but I'm not sure if it would halt the process/prevent feedback.

Comment: What about opening up two shells? Also, are you using Heroku for both deployment ***and*** source control? Would it be possible to just use something like GitHub for hosting remote repos, and only using Heroku for deployment?

Comment: @cupcake Opening two shells does work (;o]) but sometimes I forget about the *right* shell to use and have to wait. And no, my use case doesn't only use Heroku but also Github for hosting. However, I don't feel it's really relevant since I still have to push my changes to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that if the pre-receive hook fails, it exits with an exit code. That would probably mean that the `git push` itself exists with a non-zero exit code.

If that's the case, you can run a small wrapper: git push, redirect all output to a file, and when done check the exit code. If success, notify yourself however you like (email? beep?). If failure -- same, and you can check the output in the temporary file.

That wrapper you would run "in the background": `git_push_wrapper.sh mybranch &`.

If you really wanted you could also "detach" within the script itself (daemonize it), so you could run without the `&` and not get the `[1] 4844` and the `[1]+ Done`.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better heroku-specific solution, but you can try `git push &`. See this guy (command waits for 10 second and prints "foo" to stdout):

```
$ sleep 10 && echo -e "\nfoo" &
[1] 4844
echo "doing my thing"
doing my thing
$
foo
echo "keep doing my thing"
keep doing my thing
[1]+  Done                    sleep 10 && echo -e "\nfoo"
```

Comment: I thought about this one, but one gets "visually interrupted" by the output of the hook.